# How to set active class in vue 3 on active item when clicked

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I created an array and passed it to li with v-for loop.

And if i click on an element it should get active class.

I tried to do this but none of them getting active class, am i missing something?

It should be typescript enabled, as we can see in code also.

```
<template>
   <ul class="items">
        <li
          class="item"
          v-for="(item, index) in items"
          :key="index"
          @click="selectItem(index)"
          :class="{'active' : isActive}"
        >
          {{ item }}
        </li>
      </ul>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue"
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Test",
  props: {    
    id: Number,
    item: Object,
  },
  setup(props) {
    let selectedItem
    let isActive = false
    
    const items = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    const selectItem = (index: number) => {
      
      items.forEach((item) => {        
        return (isActive = item === items[index])
      })
    }
    
    return {
      items,
      selectedItem,
      selectItem,
      isActive,
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

Comment: where is your active class? I see no CSS

Comment: i just want to add the class in html, i do not want to add css right now,

Comment: Your code does not do what you wanted since you bind the isActive class on all of the elements, that is a static variable, vue has no idea which element you want active, it actually should give the active class to every one of your elements if isActive is true. 
What you could do( i will detail this in an answer later). Just save the index of the item you clicked in a variable and use that in the template to check which index is active.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#class-and-style-bindings this was quite helpful for anyone that needs a straightforward solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used selectedItem.value in setup.

This is because in the setup function, selectedItem has a type of Ref, where in the template the internal value is directly available that's why we use there as selectedItem simply.

Also i modified :class code a bit which makes it work.

```
<template>
   <ul class="items">
        <li
          class="item"
          v-for="(item, index) in items"
          :key="index"
          @click="selectItem(index)"
          :class="{ active: index == selectedItem }"
        >
          {{ item }}
        </li>
      </ul>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent,ref } from "vue"
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Test",
  props: {    
    id: Number,
    item: Object,
  },
  setup(props) {
    const selectedItem = ref(0)
    let isActive = false
    
    const items = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    const selectItem = (i: number) => {
  selectedItem.value = i
  items.forEach((item, index) => {
    return (isActive = item == items[index])
  })
  return selectedItem
 
}
    
    return {
      items,
      selectedItem,
      selectItem,
      isActive,
    }
  },
})
</script>
```